# Can't optimize line chart using MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview, mpandroidchart

I am trying to make a good looking line chart iwht [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), but I am having some problems.
Here is what I got now
[image]

and here is the code for it

```
public void createGraph() {
    chart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    chart.setDragEnabled(false);
    chart.setHighlightEnabled(false);
    chart.setDrawYLabels(true);
    chart.setDrawXLabels(true);
    chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
    chart.setDrawBorder(true);
    chart.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    setData();
}

private void setData() {
    String[] stages = { "Stage1", "Stage2", "Stage3", "Stage4" };
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    yVals.add(new Entry(0.0f, 0));
    yVals.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(nicotineTwo), 1));
    yVals.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(nicotineThree), 2));
    yVals.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(nicotineFour), 3));
    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
    set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
    set1.setLineWidth(1f);
    ArrayList<LineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<LineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    LineData data = new LineData(stages, dataSets);
    chart.setData(data);
}
```

What I need is:

1. Remove that black box under the lower left corner
2. Make the text "Nicotine Lowered" somewhat bigger and more readable
3. Add some padding or something, because the Stage4 at the top right is out of the screen
4. Make the numbers along the line bigger and if possible with percents "25.0%"
5. Hide the first value on the line, since it will always be 0
6. Show all the scale values on the Y scale, from 0 to 100 (right now there is no 100)

Please help me, this library is realy confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The "black-box" is the legend.
   Call `chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false)` to disable it.
2. That is the "description-text". Call `chart.setDescriptionTextSize(...)` to customize its size.
3. There are two possible solutions. You can either add more margin via .xml, or call

   ```
   XAxis x = chart.getXAxis();
   x.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
   ```
4. For increasing the value text size, call `data.setValueTextSize(...)`. For customly formatting values inside the chart, check out the `ValueFormatter` interface the library provides.
5. Can also be solved with the `ValueFormatter` interface. e.g. `if(value == 0) return "";`
6. Right now the range of values on the y-axis is automatically determined by the chart. You can set a fixed range of values by calling `yAxis.setAxisMaxValue(...)` & `yAxis.setAxisMinValue(...)`.

Here is the [full documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! There are some problems though, the chart.setDescriptionTextSize(...) didnt do anything, also, I am still getting the numbers on the chart cliping out of the graph, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`chart.setDescriptionTextSize(...)` has a limited range (7f to 14f). Maybe that's why you don't notice any changes.

Javadoc

> sets the size of the description text in pixels, min 7f, max 14f